# Android studio Expand Bottom Sheet on button click Inside its Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

I have a Bottom Sheet and I want to add a button in which the bottom sheet dialog expands on click

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UuV5.png)

Is it doable to put onclicklistener inside bottom sheet fragment onCreateView and change the state of the dialog?

heres my Bottom Sheet Fragment

```
public class RepliesToComment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        dialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED); <--change to STATE_EXPANDED on click-->

        return dialog;
    }


ImageButton expandBtn;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_replies_to_comment, container, false);
    {...}

    expandBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ----   
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work heres my solution

dialog to global then made a boolean identifier to switch the state of the dialog

```
boolean identifier = true;
BottomSheetDialog dialog;

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);


    return dialog;
}

public void expand(){
    if (!identifier){
        dialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }else {
        dialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }
}
```

then made the button into toggle button to change the value of the identifier

```
//expand
    expandBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            identifier = b;
            expand();
        }
    });
```